# Why does AndroidStudio become transparent after project launch?

Tags: android, android-studio, application-launch

When I launch AndroidStudio, the software opens up just fine. However, when I select a project to open, the software shows that its still running however its transparent or the window just doesn't open. I get pop ups and tooltips, but I can't see anything else. I don't get any errors or crash messages either.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling AndroidStudio, but nothing seems to work. Its been happening for a week now. I can only get as far as the project selection page after launching the software. When I select the project, the software goes invisible but I can still interact somewhat. Anyone know whats happening? Is there a solution to this? I'm running the latest version of AndroidStudio.

[AndroidStudio launching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqMKd.png)

[Projects page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpMhH.png)

[After launching project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD9F2.jpg)

See how I can access small menu options with keyboard shortcuts, here I'm pressing ctrl+`

Comment: What OS do you use? Can you provide a screenshot how AS looks in this "transparent mode"?

Comment: @Robert, I had screenshots included, but was forced to remove them because I don't have enough reputation score. I'm running the software on Windows 11.

Comment: @Robert I added images, but they got linked externally by the editor, I don't know how to make them appear with the post. Hopefully that's not too much of a problem.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. But first, try using Alt+Space, then *Move*. You can then move the window with the arrow keys. It may be off-screen.

Comment: @DanielB That Alt+Space shortcut did the trick! Thank you, thank you, thank you! For whatever reason, the window essentially shrunk itself out of screen, when I used the shortcut to move, I could only get a corner of it back on the desktop, so I chose maximize and now everything shows up. Again, thank you!

Comment: Great to hear that helped. As such, I am proposing to close this question as a duplicate (hence the automated comment above).

Comment: @DanielB Yes, that link pretty much answer the question.